# Client of root injected service not instantiated if used in a service that is provided in a component

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

i am currently struggling with the following situation in a project i am working on:

I have a CoreModule which provides a `SessionService` and takes care of the `APP_INITIALIZER`:

```js
export function initApp(initializer: AppInitializingService) {
  return () =>
    new Promise<any>(async (resolve: any) => {
      await initializer.init();
      resolve();
    });
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
   ...,
    SessionService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initApp,
      deps: [AppInitializingService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

The `APP_INITIALIZER` takes care of instantiating a Client within the `SessionService`:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppInitializingService {
  constructor(private session: SessionService) {}

  public async init(): Promise<void> {
    this.session.init();
  }
```

The `SessionService` looks like the following:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SessionService {

  public Client: Client;

  public init(): void {
    this.Client = new Client();
  }
}
```

Now i have a lazy loaded Module which has a `StoreService` that uses the `SessionService`-Client to make HTTP requests:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StoreService {

  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {
  }

  public doSomeHttpRequest() {
    this.sessionService.Client.getData().then(...);
  }
}
```

If i use `providedIn: root` in the `StoreService` everything is fine and the service works as expected inside the lazy loaded module. But i want to provide the `StoreService` in a component of the lazy loaded module, so i change my code like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class StoreService {
...
}

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [StoreService]
})
export class DelegationsComponent {
  
  constructor(private store: StoreService) {}

}
```

If i now try to do a HTTP request by `store.doSomeHttpRequest()`, i get an error that `Client` is undefined. So to sum up:

- Providing `StoreService` via `providedIn: root` works fine
- Providing `StoreService` via `DelegationsComponent` providers does not work
- In both cases `StoreService` is instantiated, but the Client which is injected by a `SessionService` singleton isn't when provided via the components providers

Comment: where do you provide SessionService?

Comment: most likely there are several instances of SessionService provided on different injection nodes, and, by moving the StoreService instance you inject another instance of SessionService - the one that is wasn't initialized

Comment: @Andrei I think what you mentioned is the key point. According to the official angular documentation: 
_[...] When the Angular router lazy-loads a module, it creates a new injector. This injector is a child of the root application injector. [...] Any component created within a lazy loaded module’s context, such as by router navigation, gets the local instance of the service, not the instance in the root application injector. [...]_

This might be the reason why i get a new instance of the service and not the one that has been initialized during startup.

Comment: exactly. but that is not the only way to create injection node, so more information on where this service is provided is required to help you with your problem